# How do you inject an arbitrary/changing set of services into an object using Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, autofac

Using Autofac, given multiple interfaces in constructor parameters which is not what I want to achieve, let's say I have;

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDomainService _domainService;
    private readonly IService1 _service1;
    private readonly IService2 _service2;
    private readonly IService3 _service3;

    public SomeController(IDomainService domainService,
                              Iservice1 service1,
                              IService2 service2,
                              IService2 service3, ...)
    {
        _domainService = domainService;
        _service1 = service1;
        _service2 = service2;
        _service3 = service3;
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, we may do one interface and has multiple properties, e.g.;

```
public interface IAllServices
{
    IDomainService DomainService { get; set; }
    IService1 Service1 { get; set; }
    IService2 Service2 { get; set; }
    IService3 Service3 { get; set; }
}

public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAllServices _allServices;

    public SomeController(IAllServices allServices)
    {
        _allServices = allServices;

        var domainService1 = _allServices.DomainService;
        var service1 = _allServices.Service1;
        etc...
    }
}
```

However, I would like to have a list of services, and this code works for me, i.e.;

```
public interface IMyApp
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> Services { get; set; }
}

public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyApp _myapp;

    public SomeController(IMyApp myapp)
    {
        _myapp = myapp;

        foreach (var item in _myapp.Services)
        {
            if (item is IService1) { // do something... }
            if (item is IService2) { // do something... }
            if (item is IWhatever) { // do whatever something... }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I don't have a better best practice how to create the module, here is my module;

```
public class MainModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly string[] _serviceNames;
    private readonly IDomainService _domainService;

    public MainModule(IDomainService domainService, params string[] serviceNames)
    {
        _serviceNames = serviceNames;
        _domainService = domainService;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        List<dynamic> _services = new List<dynamic>();

        _services.Add(_domainService);

        foreach (var serviceName in _serviceNames)
        {
            switch (serviceName)
            {
                case "MyService1":
                    IService1 service1 = new Service1();
                    _modules.Add(service1);
                    break;
                case "MyService2":
                    IService2 service2 = new Service2();
                    _modules.Add(service2);
                    break;
                case "SomeWhateverService":
                    IWhatever whateverService = new WhateverService();
                    _modules.Add(whateverService);
                    break;                      
            }

        }

        builder.RegisterType<MyApp>()
            .As<IMyApp>()
            .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>), _services));

    }
}
```

So, this code works, but I would like to make my DomainService and all of the Services registered in the container as well. That is, I want to replace whatever inside the switch statement without *new* keyword.

```
IService1 service1 = new Service1();
_modules.Add(service1);
```

And I would like to register the domain service as well. So, inside my Bootstrapper is like this;

```
public static class Initializer
{
    public static IContainer BuildContainer(
        HttpConfiguration config, Assembly assembly, IDomainService domainService, params string[] services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
        builder.RegisterModule(new MainModule(domainService, services));

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        return container;
    }
}
```

And what happen is, I need to create the domain service in the startup, i.e.;

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        MyDomainService domainService = new MyDomainService();

        var container =
            Initializer.BuildContainer(
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration,
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            domainService,
            "MyService1", "MyService2", "SomeWhateverService");

    }
}
```

You can see that I have to create the domain service first, which is not using IoC;

```
MyDomainService domainService = new MyDomainService();
```

and add to the module.

The big question, how to do this in proper way using Autofac. My Bootstrapper is in another project and all of the interfaces are in other project as well.

Many thanks for the help. And sorry for the long question.

**Solution**:
After testing several model, it seems the best way is to use **domain events** model for this type of scenario instead of injecting the services into the domain.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing dependency injection is using Constructor Injection. Constructor Injection should always your preferred choice, and only under high exception, you should fall back to another method.

You proposed property injection as an alternative, but this causes [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) which means that classes can be initialized while a required dependency is missing, causing null reference exceptions later on.

The method where you inject a collection containing all services where the constructor is responsible of getting the dependencies it needs, is a variation of the [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). This pattern is littered with problems and [is considered to be an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Grouping dependencies into a new class and injecting that is only useful in case that class *encapsulates logic and hides the dependencies*. This pattern is called [Facade Service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). Having one big service that exposes the dependencies for others to use can be considered a form of the Service Locator anti-pattern, especially when the number of services that this class exposes starts to grow. It will become the common go-to object for getting services. Once that happens, it exhibits the same downsides as the other form of Service Locator does.

Extracting dependencies into a different class while allowing the consumer to use those dependencies directly doesn't help in reducing complexity of the consumer. That consumer will keep the same amount of logic and the same number of dependencies.

The core problem here seems that your classes get too many dependencies. The great thing about constructor injection though is that it makes it very clear when classes have too many dependencies. Seeking other methods to get dependencies doesn't make the class less complex. Instead of trying other methods of injection, try the following:

- Apply the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Classes should have one reason to change.
- Try extracting logic with its dependencies out of the class into a *Facade Service*
- Remove logic and dependencies that deals with cross-cutting concerns (such as logging and security checks) from the class and place them in infrastructure (such as decorators, interceptors or depending on your framework into handlers, middleware, message pipeline, etc).

Comment: This is not the answer I want. I don't think I ask for property injection. I just want to know for my solution -as in the code- using Autofac. This architecture can be done in Unity, but I don't know how to do it in Autofac as best practice. The code works in Autofac, however I need to make the domain services and the other services to be part of a list in the constructor.

Comment: @Rize: Please stick to using best practices. Constructor injection with a list of typed parameters is best practice. Anything else *is not*.

Comment: the services which is in the module is part of the infrastructure which is can be configured from the domain. The domain service is design for that specific domain. I also added the domain events handler in the infrastructure.

Comment: If you look at the **Module** part and how to simplify this or if you have better way to achieve a constructor injection with one interface and a property in it, that is `IEnumerable<dynamic> Services { get; set; }` that would be helpful.

Comment: @Riza: As I stated in my answer: you should **not** inject an interface that contains properties with dependencies and you should not inject an `IEnumerable<object>` with the list of available services in the application.

Comment: Steven, Noted with thanks. The class has single responsibility, yet require certain services which the interface cannot be hardcoded as parameters. I can take out such as ILogger and put as parameter, however, other independent services can be more than 10 interfaces as parameters and can be vary depends on configuration. That is why I wanted to use dynamic object as list. I can, however, load by the assembly itself but that would polluted the domain class with container builders. I try using aspect but is more difficult. Now, if it is not like this, any better way would be good for me to try.

Comment: @Riza: It is really hard to give specific feedback on an abstract description. Please post a concrete code example for a "service [with] more than 10 interfaces as parameters and can be vary depends on configuration". If you post such sample, please don't obfuscate any class, method or dependency names, since those names give a lot of information for me (or anyone else) to base the feedback on.

Comment: The interfaces is not part of the infrastructure such as repositories, database, cache, logging, etc. You get the idea, is other than that. My last option might be using NServiceBus or possibly Microservices model. But, I'm not going to give up with dependency injection yet.

Comment: @Riza Messaging, Micro Servces and Dependency Injection are *not* mutually exclusive techniques. When implementing a micro service that uses messaging, I would still recomend using DI as a way to get your code base testable and maintainable.

Comment: What is your solution with DI? Just assume you have 10 dynamic services that needs to be injected. How would you do it with DI.

Comment: @Riza I need to see your specific use case to be able to answer your question.

Comment: You can assume as any use cases such as scientific app. The idea is you need to inject variety of dynamic services can 2, 4, 10, 15 interfaces in the constructor.

Comment: @Riza Sending in an arbitrary list of services is tantamount to service location rather than dependency injection. I'd recommend changing your design to avoid that, but it seems you are "steering" the discussion such that only one outcome is possible. Avoid code that has switches and checks that "know" about service types and change behavior based on that. It's a bad design smell.

Comment: @TravisIllig any better suggestions? the domain app are also not only one. It can be several domain apps using the variety of services. Example, one app might use Servcie1 & 2 other app can use Service1,4,7 & 10. If you have any better suggestions, perhaps a link to some article that would be helpful. I'm open to other architecture, but the above scenario is clear. What should I do if I use DI with Autofac for this scenario. My code works perfectly and no issue so far. However, I need all of the components resolved by DI & not using _new_ keyword in the module, including domain services.

Answer (score 0):

After testing several model, it seems the best way is just use **domain events** pattern for this type of scenario instead of injecting the services into the domain.

I refer to Udi Dahan article on domain events:
http://udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/